# Conditional Mapping ((condition) ? get-this : get-that) with Org.ModelMapper

Tags: java, modelmapper

I'm trying to conditionally use one getter or another depending on a condition of the root/source of the map. `A` has a reference to `B`; however, it (the reference) is *allowed to be null*. When the reference is *not null* I'd like to use a property from it (`B`). However, when the reference *is null* I'd like to use a property from the source (`A`).

It's a little business-logic'y but there are a lot of data-models in our system here that follow this sort of pattern. It'd be beneficial to use a mapper library and in my mind the logic is simple enough - it's extremely similar to using the library's `Condition`.

When I use the logic in the getter it will boot up and initialize fine; however, when the map is actually used to map an object  I get an `IllegalArgumentException` from Model-Mapper which says `object is not an instance of declaring class`.

I haven't been able to properly fit the library's `Condition` into a solution. It appears to be more of a one-and-done, instead of an if-or-else. I have a mapper which first uses the getter on the source (`A`). On the next line I then call a conditional `Conditions.isNotNull())` and map `a -> a.getB().getDescription()`. So in my head how it would work is it would first set the DTO's `description` property using `A`. It would then "overwrite" that value with `a.getB().getDescription()` but only if `a.getB()` was not null. However, it does not appear to work that way. Instead, for the instances that `a.getB()` returns null I see `null` as the DTO's `description`.

In summary, I'm looking to be able to do something like the following:

```
modelMapper.createTypeMap(A.class, FlatAB.class).addMappings(mapper -> {
    mapper.map(a -> a.getB() != null ? a.getB().getDescription() : 
            a.getDescription(), FlatAB::setDescription);
});
```

Here's some sample code to demonstrate the problem I'm facing.

```
import java.util.Optional;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;

public class TestMappingConditionalGettersWithModelMapper {

  @Test
  public void testConditionalGetter() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    modelMapper.createTypeMap(A.class, FlatAB.class).addMappings(mapper -> {

      // mapper.map(a -> a.getB() != null ? a.getB().getDescription() : a.getDescription(), FlatAB::setDescription);

      mapper.map(a -> Optional
          .ofNullable(a.getB())
          .map(B::getDescription)
          .orElseGet(a::getDescription), FlatAB::setDescription);
    });

    // first try A with no relationship
    A a = new A();
    a.setDescription("description of A");
    FlatAB flatAB1 = modelMapper.map(a, FlatAB.class);
    Assert.assertEquals("they should equal", a.getDescription(), flatAB1.getDescription());


    // now try it WITH a relationship
    A a2 = new A();
    a2.setDescription("description of A2");
    B b = new B();
    b.setDescription("description of B");
    a2.setB(b);
    FlatAB flatAB2 = modelMapper.map(a2, FlatAB.class);
    Assert.assertEquals("they should equal", b.getDescription(), flatAB2.getDescription());
  }

}

class A {

  private String description;
  private B b;

  /*
   .....
   .....
   many other properties
   .....
   ....
   */

  public B getB() {
    return b;
  }

  public void setB(B b) {
    this.b = b;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

}

class B {

  private String description;

  /*
   .....
   .....
   many other properties
   .....
   ....
   */

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: It's a little hard to follow your text, can you provide a short code snippet to illustrate your problem?

Comment: sorry, I'll edit with a summarized / quick-version

Comment: okay, the summarized question's in there at the bottom :+1:

Answer (score 4):

[I popped the question over on the library's Github](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/376) and received a terrific answer from the maintainer, [Chun-Han, Hsiao](https://github.com/chhsiao90).

> We can't map multiple source properties to a destination without a converter.
>
> Please try:

```
modelMapper.addMappings(mapper ->
    mapper.using(ctx -> ctx.getSource().getB() != null
        ? ctx.getSource().getB().getDescription()
        : ctx.getSource().getDescription())
      .map(src -> src, FlatAB::setDescription));
```

I found that`ctx.getSource()` may require casting -- but I'm sure there's a way to feed the type.

Comment: Actually, using an AbsractConverter takes care of the type casting issue. It's the same code as above, except the lambda in using is formalized into an AbstractConverter.

        `Converter<A, String> converter = new AbstractConverter<>() {
        @Override
        protected String convert(A source) {
            return source.getB() == null ? null : source.getB().getDescription();
        }
    };
    map.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(converter).map(source -> source, (destination, value) -> destination.setDescription((String) value))
    );`

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, I would go smth like

```
Optional
    .ofNullable(a.getB())
    .map(B::getDescription)
    .orElseGet(a::getDescription)
```

This would produce B-description if b is not null, A-description otherwise.

UPDATE

Putting above code to separate method will do the trick A.getMappingDescription() like :

```
class A {
            String desc;
            B b;
            public String getMappingDescription() {
                return Optional
                        .ofNullable(getB())
                        .map(B::getDesc)
                        .orElse(desc);
            }
...
}
```

And your mapping will be simpler :

```
modelMapper.createTypeMap(A.class, FlatAB.class).addMapping(A::getMappingDescription, FlatAB::setDesc);
```

UPDATE 2

You can simply extract that converter specifying concrete generic type like:

```
Converter<A, String> descriptionConverter = ctx -> ctx.getSource().getB() != null
        ? ctx.getSource().getB().getDesc()
        : ctx.getSource().getDesc();

mapper.using(descriptionConverter).map(src -> src, FlatAB::setDesc);
```

Or cast explicitly like:

```
((Converter<A, String>) ctx -> ctx.getSource().getB()..
```

Comment: Unfortunately this causes the same illegal-argument-exception that is thrown with the other attempts: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class`

Comment: In response to the edit: yes, of course that works -- but it's what I'm trying to avoid. That'd have me messing with entities/data-models and we have to avoid that.